# How would I fix the "Invalid syntax" error?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a script that when you type in something, it adds it to a table then prints the table. Then, it asks if you want to continue adding something to the table. If you say "yes", then the function starts again. If you don't say yes, nothing happens. Why isn't this working? (sorry it's probably a noob mistake)

```
color_list = []

def add_to_color_list():
    print("Say something")
    color_list.append(input())

    print(color_list)
    print("Continue?")
    input()
    answer = input()

    if answer = "yes": 
        add_to_color_list()
  

add_to_color_list()
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You have an extra call to `input()` that you don't use the result of.

Comment: What does the rest of the error message say? The entire error output contains useful information that will point you to the problem

Comment: Is `List` supposed to be `colorList`?

Comment: That's all it says sorry

Comment: List is not color list, I just had to update it because I copied the wrong version

Comment: `if answer = "yes":` should use `==` for comparison. You can't do an assignment in `if`.

Comment: How strange, the error message should have more information. What environment are you running this code in? Is it IDLE? A website python interpreter?

Comment: The two calls to `input()` mean you have to answer `Continue?` twice.

Comment: I'm running it in an IDE called Mu

Comment: @MIfoodie Your IDE should tell you which line causes the error. That is always the place to start to figure out how to fix syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple mistakes in your code.

1st: you append the input to `colorList`, but you define your list as `List`

2nd: you have `answer = input()`, but call `input()` again up top. It's not necessary to call it twice (only use `answer = input()` so you can save it)

3rd: when checking if the answer is equal to yes, use == instead of =, = is the assignment operator

Some other things could be added like making the input lowercase so "Yes" would work, and printing out code in the input instead of using print and input

Here is the working code:

```
colorList = []
def e():
    colorList.append(input("Say something\n"))
    print(colorList)
    answer = input("Continue?\n")
    if answer == "yes": 
        e()
  

e()
```

Use `answer = input("Continue?\n").lower()` to make it not case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use `==` not `=` to compare values, your mistake is on line **9**.

Comment: This is true, but it won't cause a syntax error.

Comment: my bad its actually line 9

Comment: The line number doesn't matter, it's still not a syntax error.

Comment: @Barmar: What do you mean? `if answer = "yes":` is a syntax error in Python...

Comment: My comments were before you edited, when you said the problem was with the `input()` line.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this in Mu, I get the following error:

```
  File "c:\...\color_list.py", line 9
    if answer = "yes":
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Notice there is much more here than just "invalid syntax" as you claimed. Be sure that you read and understand the entire error message. For example, this tells you the exact line of code that is causing the problem. That is the place to start. And as someone else already answers, you need to replace `=` with `==` to fix the error.